# ASP.Net ListView give Blank Records for Special Characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a asp.net ListView control which is bound to a data source using the DataSourceId.

```
<asp:ListView ID="myListView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="*****" DataSourceID="myDataSource">
```

The Data source gets data from the SQL Server using the `myDataSource.SelectCommand`.

In the resulting list view, rows blanks out where there are special characters such as **é**
in the sql table row. (double checked using SQL Management Studio)

I think this may be due to a UNICODE issue, but how can i solve this issue in the ListView ?

Comment: have u tried using simple char not unicode is that work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a issue with Listview, it looks when you are pulling out data in .net, these Unicode is getting converted to blank spaces.

This is just a example with textfile having UniCode

```
 using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\input.txt", Encoding.Unicode))
    {
        label1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

You can try with this and will understand what I am trying to say.